# get part of mp3 using http Range header (with seconds)

Tags: http, header, range, byte, mp3

I have mp3 files, and I have the time in seconds.milliseconds of the part I want

how can I get that using Range header in HTTP call ?

this is the file
https://mirrors.quranicaudio.com/muqri/alghamidi/mp3/001.mp3

and the time I want is from the second: **3.500** until **6.526**

Answer (score 0):

You can't with the only interoperable range unit, which is "bytes".

That said, if the MP3 has a fixed encoding rate you might be able to compute an approximation of the byte offset.

Comment: can you explain the compute thing please

Comment: If you know the bitrate, and have read the MP3 headers, you should be able to compute the offset.